# line-height: leading not to be splitted in before and after the line (for good typography)

Tags: html, css

I have a two columns grid. The left column's font-size and line-height are twice as big as on the right.

The idea is: every second baseline on the right matches a baseline of the left column (for good typography).

However, this doesnt work, because the "line-height" splits the leading (the gap between the text) in before-line and after-line (in contrast to lead-typesetting).

It coud work if the whole leading comes after or before the line but how could I do that ?

Example : https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/c7ce94-1553775633.png
Thats how it should look like: https://bilder-upload.eu/upload/ce728b-1553777442.png

(I tried it with a different margin of the left column but this is not precise and kind of botched. and on every font its another value which has to be guessed!)

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.one,
.two {
    line-height: 1;
}

.one {
    font-size: 36px;
}

.two {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="one">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxXx<br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxXx</div>
  <div class="two">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxXx<br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxXx<br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxXx<br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxXx</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO g0l4m, could you provide a screenshot of the desired result ?

Comment: of course: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/ce728b-1553777442.png   here the baselines matches

Comment: the baseline can't match. I mean the texts cannot be positioned at the bottom the same. Because of the `line-height`. First div has `line-height` of 36px second has 18px. So the 'distance' top/bottom from the text is bigger in the first div than in the second. So they don't line up.  Here you can see better what i am talking about https://jsfiddle.net/opdu9mzc/ You can achieve what you want but not with line-height

Comment: thank you! but the different sizes were intendet. i want every second baseline on the right matches one at the left.
how yould you archive it without line-height?

Comment: The only way I could think of would be to set a fixed height to your content and then to play with `align-items` on your grid setup. The second one is basically playing with `margin` and `padding`, that's what I did in both of these jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s0paxr4g/ (margin), https://jsfiddle.net/s0paxr4g/1/ (padding)

Comment: thank you very much! i did it using padding-top.
(i hope someday css allowes this to do this precicely :) ```line-height: 1 half-leading```, ```line-height: 20px baseline-baseline``` ```line-height: 5px baseline-ascender``` or something … https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading#On_the_World_Wide_Web )